# How to find out if a specific set of ids exists in DB in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got the following table:

```
userId|imageId|
------|-------|
     1|      1|
     1|      2|
     1|      3|
```

and in a special validator I want to make sure that those imageIds I'm given (let's say, `2` and `3`) exist in this table and belong to a user with `userId = 1`;

How do I do that in Postgres?

My PostgreSQL is 12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch count of records that matched:

```
select count(imageId) from table_name where userId=1 and imageId in (2, 3);
```

Check if count matches the length of given `imageId` list and return true or false based on that:

```
if query.first()[0] >= len(imageIdList):
     return True
return False
```

Comment: yeah basically in my case I can do something like: `select uii."imageId" from user_images_image uii where uii."userId" = 1 and uii."imageId" in (1, 5, 4);` but it will return `1`, that's to say it will return those ids that do exist, indeed then I could compare the result to the initial list of ids and based on the result of this comparison return true or false in my validator but is there a less verbose way to do that? Ideally, I would like to return something if all of the specified ids are in the DB and return nothing if at least one of them is missing. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You could do that by comparing the number of records that matched and number of imageId's that were given. See my updated answer.